# What can we say about $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$ if $g^\alpha$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Question**: Suppose $p>3$ is prime and $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$

What can one say about $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$ if $g^\alpha$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$

---

**Attempt**: Let $m\in\mathbb{N}^+$, let $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $(a,m)=1$

Let $h\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ be least s.t. $a^h\equiv 1\pmod{m}$, then $a$ belongs to $h\pmod{m}$

If $g$ belongs to exponent $\phi(m)\pmod{m}$, then $g$ is called a  primitive root modulo $m$

When $(a,m)=1$, we say that $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $m$ provided that $x^2\equiv a\pmod{m}$ is soluble

From these definitions we can deduce that $g$ a primitive root modulo $p$ implies

$\phi(p)\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ is least s.t. $g^{\phi(p)}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ and $(g,p)=1$, so $(g^\alpha,p)=1$, $\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$

$g^\alpha$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ if the congruence $x^2\equiv g^\alpha\pmod{p}$ is soluble

"What can we say about $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$" is the same as saying "for what values of $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$ is $x^2\equiv g^\alpha\pmod{p}$ soluble"

Comment: Hint: You are supposed to answer questions like A) Is $g^\alpha$ a quadratic residue, when $\alpha=5$? B) Is $g^\alpha$ a quadratic residue, when $\alpha=6$?  et cetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $g$ is a primitive root of $p$, $$g^{(p-1)/2}\equiv-1\pmod{p} $$

Next from [Euler's citerion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) we have
$$\left(g^{\alpha}\right)^{(p-1)/2} = \left(g^{(p-1)/2}\right)^{\alpha}\equiv  (-1)^{\alpha} \pmod{p}$$

Clearly, $\alpha$ must be even for $g^{\alpha}$ to be a quadratic residue.

---

Alternatively you may conclude your work by taking discrete logarithm

$$x^2\equiv g^\alpha\pmod{p} \implies 2\text{ind}_g x\equiv \alpha \pmod{p-1}$$

Since $\gcd(2,p-1)=2$, we must have $2|\alpha$
 for above linear congruence to be solvable.

Comment: Would the downvoter, please, care to comment?